# how to deal with zend meta data cache

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-cache

I am working on a project developed in zend framework. The developer who worked already has used `zend metadata cache` and using zend function `info()` to get metadata of the table.

Now I have inserted a new field `status` in the table. Now the table is not returning the new field.

The code for creating cache is as follow

```
$frontendOptions = array(
        'automatic_serialization' => true,
        'lifetime' => 100000,
        'cache_id_prefix' => 'metaData_',
    );
    $backendOptions = array();
    $cache = Zend_Cache::factory(
        'Core', 
        'File',
        $frontendOptions,
        $backendOptions
    );
    Zend_Db_Table_Abstract::setDefaultMetadataCache($cache);
```

I tried to delete the cache by using

```
$cache = Zend_Cache::factory();
Zend_Db_Table_Abstract::setDefaultMetadataCache($cache);
$cache->clean(Zend_Cache::CLEANING_MODE_ALL);
```

Can somebody tell me how to deal with this problem?

Comment: @Gordon what is the expected file location?

Comment: What you configured it to be. And if you didnt configure it's the default given in the Reference Guide: http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.cache.backends.html

Comment: In your second code snippet you don't setup the factory with any options. Is this how you do it? Then the clean method is not aware of `file` backend.

Comment: since you haven't specified the cache directory (cache_dir) in the `$backendOptions` the directory will be taken as the default directory, which is the temp directory of the server. [Zend_Cache_Backend_Options] (http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.cache.backends.html)